# OpenMP - "#pragma omp critical" importance

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

So I started using OpenMP (multithreading) to increase the speed of my matrix multiplication and I witnessed weird things: **when I turn off OpenMP Support** (in Visual Studio 2019) **my nested for-loop completes 2x faster.** So I removed "#pragma omp critical" to test if it slows down the proccess significantly and **the proccess went 4x faster than before** (with OpenMP Support **On**).

Here's my question: **is "#pragma omp critical" important in nested loop? Can't I just skip it?**

```
        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3)
        for (int i = 0; i < this->I; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.J; j++)
            {
                m.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < A.I; k++)
                {   
                        #pragma omp critical
                        m.matrix[i][j] += this->matrix[i][k] * A.matrix[k][j];                                            
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here's my question: is "#pragma omp critical" important in nested
> loop? Can't I just skip it?

If the matrices `m`, `this` and `A` are different you do not need any critical region. Instead, you need to ensure that each thread will write to a different position of the matrix `m` as follows:

```
       #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
        for (int i = 0; i < this->I; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.J; j++)
            {
                m.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < A.I; k++)
                {   
                    m.matrix[i][j] += this->matrix[i][k] * A.matrix[k][j];                                            
                }
            }
        }
```

The `collapse` clause will assign to each thread a different pair `(i, j)` therefore there will not be multiple threads writing to the same position of the matrix `m` (*i.e.,* race-condition).

Comment: Thank you for the explaination:) I'll use your method

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma omp critical` is necessary here, as there is a (remote) chance that two threads could write to a particular `m.matrix[i][j]` value. It hurts performance because only one thread at a time can access that protected assignment statement.

This would likely be better without the `collapse` part (then you can remove the `#pragma omp critical`). Accumulate the sums to a temporary local variable, then store it in `m.matrix[i][j]` after the `k` loop finishes.